# Dynamic class in ember template

Tags: class, templates, dynamic, ember.js, view

I've started to use Ember.js after coming from Angular (I'm trying and learning different frameworks).
Could someone could explain me how is it possible to create dynamic classes in an Ember template ?
I've read the docs, but I must say that it's still a bit obscure for me.

This is what I want to do :

```
<div class="myClass-{{id}}></div>
```

Where **{{id}}** is equivalent to item id in json.
I don't know if it can help but I alos use Ember View for that template.

Thanks for your time and andswer !

Comment: look up the `{{bind-attr}}` helper

Comment: just out of curiousity: why do you use a dynamically generated `class`  instead of the (provided and unique) `elementId` which is the HTML Element `id`? it seems like you want to identify your HTML Element and looking it up via `id` is much faster than via `class`... do you have some elements which share the same id?

Comment: @herom : No, I don't have elements which share the same id. The reason of why I want to do that (but maybe, I'm thinking about it the wrong way :)) is because I have to trigger a countdown with jquery. Since the time is different depending of the page, I would trigger each call with a specific class. But, yes, an Id would also be good, and as you mentioned it, better.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to do that anyhow this 'could' work through just normal `{{bind-attr}}` helper

```
<div {{bind-attr class=someProperty}}></div>
```

If the data is generated via a user action. Then in the the receiver of the action (in the controller) you can do the following:

```
someAction: function(id){
 this.set('someProperty', 'class-' + id);
}
```

if it is on load you can populate that property via the `model` hook or `setUpController` hook in the route

Model Hook:

```
model: function(){
 return {someProperty: 'class-' + id}; //where ever id is coming from
}
```

setupController hook:

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
  controller.set('someProperty', 'class-' + id); //where ever id is coming from
}
```

**EDIT**

In your view callback:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
  var _scope = this;
  var cb = function(){
    _scope.get('controller').set('someProperty', 'class-' + id);
  }
  //set up jquery countdown
}
```

To be safe tho if you are doing some countdown trigger in jquery it will not get into Ember's runloop so you might see some strange behaviour. Consider using `run` detailed [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/run.run.html#method_schedule)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that solution a try. FYI, I want to make that because I have to trigger a countdown with jquery (with didInsertElement in view). Since the time is different depending of the page, I would trigger each call with a specific class.